# MySQL Specific Default DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I feel like this should be an easy thing to find but having issues trying to determine the syntax for this.

I'm trying to set a default datetime value with a specific date. I've tried various syntax around this to no avail but stripped it back down for the example.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table`
(
    `start_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `end_date`   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 9999-12-31 23:59:59
);
```

Comment: It should be `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: Thanks. Ugh I had tried that and didn't pay attention and was failing in my DB load on another one that wasn't quoted so thought the original didn't work. Doh!